# JavaScript Google Maps API V3 Elevation and Directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API V3 to build a map that displays elevation that updates when you change direction with the draggable map and update the text directions panel.

Think you could help point me in the right direction?

Here is a link to the one with the Text Directions Panel and is Draggable http://bicyclevegas.com/directionswitheleval.html

Here is a link to the one with the Elevation Profile and is Draggable
http://bicyclevegas.com/elevation.html

I am having trouble mashing the two together, any pointers and assistance would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have missing:

```
dr.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
```

just under:

```
var dr = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
     map: map,
     draggable: true,
     preserveViewport: true
});
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3F8nw/

Comment: You are a life saver! One last question i want to get rid of the drop down next to the address input and have it only be defaulted to bicycle mode.

Comment: Nevermind I was able to get it